# JS : Map an array ... So simple but BrainBreaker

Tags: javascript

I face an issue with a so simple js transformation !

Here is my array

```
["one", "two"]
```

Here is what I want to output

```
["en/one", "en/one", "fr/two", "fr/two"]
```

What I'm trying to do with my knowledge

```js
let a = ["one", "two"];
let b = a.map(x => `en/${x}`,`fr/${x}`);

console.log(b);
```

But I get an error:

> ReferenceError: x is not defined

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why _would_ that work? Your example contains en and fr, not 1 and 2.

Comment: where do the values "en" and "fr" come from?

Comment: Yes sorry, it was a typo

Comment: "fr" and "en" come from nowhere, i just need to add all my localized path

Comment: @Kevin can you please update the question? It is not clear.

Comment: if the value of language more than 2 and you alway going add manually so the way is make array of object where two value store e.g obj=[{val:'fr',num:'one'},{val:'two',num:'two'}] something like that

Answer (score 3):

The way you wrote it, `` `fr/${x}` `` becomes a second argument to `.map()` (where `x` is not in scope). You need to combine the two values in an array...

And then you can use `flatMap`:

```
let b = a.flatMap(x => [`en/${x}`,`fr/${x}`]);
```